# Accidently changed type of recovery drive in Windows 7 - Not able to recover

Tags: windows-7

I have accidentally changed type of partition type of recovery drive of Windows 7. Earlier it was "Boot,Active", now it is active.
This disaster happened when I was creating partitions. Now I am not able to boot my system, when use my recovery disk it is quitting in between. Please help me out in recovering my system to normal state.
I need to change the type of recovery partition as "Boot,Active". Please help!!

Thanks in Advance
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

Try your best to boot of the installation disk and open a command prompt. Use `DISKPART` command to enter diskpart.  From here I would find the partition interfering with the boot by using `LIST VOLUME` and `DETAIL` commands, and delete it using `DELETE`. The `ACTIVE` command may help your original partition become bootable again.  You can attempt to repartition your disk again in disk management once you get it booted.  The commands you ultimately use may vary, look at the commands available in Diskpart.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not show "Boot" anymore, you may have destroyed your BCD store. You'll need a Windows installation disk on DVD or USB stick and follow [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392). You'll need to use the `/rebuildBcd` option hidden under the 'Click here to show/hide more information' link.

If you're actually missing the "active" flag (which is more likely), you can use any tool that allows you to modify your partition table. The most friendly option is some gparted live CD/USB stick. You can make one using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).